# Observable is calling multiple times?

Tags: angular

I have this in my component on init:

```
   this.subscription =  this.ups.getCustomer().subscribe((data: any) => {
                  console.log('aaa');
                   this.fillGridFromSearchPopup({'caId': data.id});
                    return;
                });
```

And in same component i have set also:

```
  this.ups.setCustomer(this.customerId, 'BA');
```

Now my service is in loop. I need to set here because user can go on there componenet where i need that id and so on. How can i call this only once and not multiple times? Any suggestion?

This is my service:

```
 setCustomer(id, accountClassCode) {
        console.log(id,accountClassCode);
        this.customer.next({ 'id': id, 'accountClassCode': accountClassCode });
    }

    getCustomer() {
        console.log(this.customer);
        return this.customer.asObservable();
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your service, please?

Comment: this is only that i use in service, its already posted

Comment: your code looking good i guess some other function calling 'setCustomer' may be fillGridFromSearchPopup .

Comment: i only set on one place for now setCustomer, maybe problem is that i set and get on same component?

Comment: That's why I requested the rest of the code, what's the type of the `this.customer`?

Comment: private customer: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();